# What is the real way for mvc to serve a filestream?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filestream

I have an incorrect way to make asp.net mvc serve a filestream. It looks like this:

```
    public void SlideThumbnail(Guid id, int? width, int? height)
    {
        /*make the thumbnail code here*/

        using (Bitmap thumbnail = imageThumb.Generate(path))
        {
            var msOutput = new MemoryStream();

            thumbnail.Save(msOutput, ImageFormat.Png);
            Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            msOutput.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }
```

This works super duper. I tried modifying the code to use `base.File()` instead. Like this:

```
    public ActionResult SlideThumbnail(Guid id, int? width, int? height)
    {
        /*make the thumbnail code here*/

        using (Bitmap thumbnail = imageThumb.Generate(path))
        {
            var msOutput = new MemoryStream();

            thumbnail.Save(msOutput, ImageFormat.Png);
            return base.File(msOutput, "image/png");
        }
    }
```

But all this doesn't seem to actually do anything. I don't get any errors, but I also don't get any image :-(

So how do i accomplish this the MVC way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out. I just needed to add:

```
thumbnail.Save(msOutput, ImageFormat.Png);
msOutput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // <--- this line
return base.File(msOutput, "image/png");
```

and we're all good.